# Reading files from a directory in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I get the list of files (or all *.txt files for example) in a directory in Scala.
The Source class does not seem to help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
new java.io.File(dirName).listFiles.filter(_.getName.endsWith(".txt"))
```

Comment: Works quite well

Answer (score 16):

The JDK7 version, using the new DirectoryStream class is:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path}
Files.newDirectoryStream(path)
    .filter(_.getFileName.toString.endsWith(".txt"))
    .map(_.toAbsolutePath)
```

Instead of a string, this returns a Path, which has loads of handy methods on it, like 'relativize' and 'subpath'.

Note that you will also need to import `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` to enable interop with Java collections.

Comment: I don't know if this has worked in previous versions, but now I get the error ` value map is not a member of java.nio.file.DirectoryStream[java.nio.file.Path] `

Comment: It sounds like you need to import the implicit conversions for Java collections: ```import scala.collection.JavaConversions._```

This adds scala methods like ```map``` to Java collections, which is great for interop with java libraries (like nio)

Comment: My mileage varied. This worked for me (in the Spark shell):  
    `scala> import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, Path};`  
    `scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._;`   
    `scala> for (file <- Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/Users/Ion/Uploads/"), "*.TXT")){`  
    `  | println(file);`  
    `  | };`

Comment: @NickCecil Your filter for text files does not work as you intended. From documentation of `endsWith` method: `...for example, the path "foo/bar" ends with "foo/bar" and "bar". It does not end with "r" or "/bar".`. This is because filter is operating on `Path` objects and not `Strings`.

Answer (score 15):

The Java File class is really all you need, although it's easy enough to add some Scala goodness to iteration over directories easier.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

for(file <- myDirectory.listFiles if file.getName endsWith ".txt"){
   // process the file
}
```

Comment: I tried to edit two little typos, but since it is just two characters, it wouldn't let me. The name of the package is `collection`, and you are missing a closing parenthesis in your `for`.

Answer (score 2):

For now, you should use Java libraries to do so.