# Unable to map over a Stream of files

Tags: scala

I am attempting to map over a Stream of files but just the first element is evaluated :

```
 var fList = Stream(new java.io.File("test1") , new java.io.File("test2"))
                                                  //> fList  : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.io.File] = Stream(test1, ?)
                                                  //| 

 fList.map(file => {
    println(file.getAbsolutePath)
 })                                               //> C:\Eclipse\scala-SDK-3.0.2-vfinal-2.10-win32.win32.x86\eclipse\test1
                                                  //| res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Unit] = Stream((), ?)
```

Reading http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/01/introducing-streams.html `Streams are a special type of Iterable/Traversable whose elements are not evaluated until they are requested. Streams are normally constructed as functions.` Since I'm using map over my Stream should each file contained within the stream be evaluated and therefore its name outputted ?

Update : I found this useful, an alternative to using Stream : [Reading files from a directory in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622364/reading-files-from-a-directory-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per `Stream.map` documentation:

> Returns the stream resulting from applying the given function f to
>   each element of this stream. This returns a lazy Stream such that it
>   does not need to be fully realized.

So using `map` does not evaluate the stream, it produces a new stream.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `map` but loop if you are after the side effect of `println`.

```
scala> var fList = Stream(new java.io.File("foo1") , new java.io.File("foo2"))
fList: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[java.io.File] = Stream(foo1, ?)

scala> fList.foreach(f => println(f.getAbsolutePath))
/tmp/foo1
/tmp/foo2

scala> fList take 2 foreach(f => println(f.getAbsolutePath))
/tmp/foo1
/tmp/foo2
```