# Scala - how to loop through only files that match a specific string in directory?

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have a directory with files that look like part-00000, part-00001, etc. There are also other files that I do not want to iterate through, so I would want to do some form of pattern matching/regex/filtering on file names that start with "part-".

How do I iterate through only the files that start with "part-"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading files from a directory in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622364/reading-files-from-a-directory-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter:

```
new File("c:/sequence-files/").listFiles.filter(_.getName.startsWith("part-")).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use this regex `part-.*` for example ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/99cw5M/1))
2. If you the rest part contain only numbers, then you can use `part-\d*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/99cw5M/2))
3. If you want to march only part- followed by 5 numbers `part-\d{5,5}` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/99cw5M/3))

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you already have the list of files:

```
object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val listOfFiles = List("part-00000", "part-00001", "randomFile", "part-00003", "randomFile2", "part-00004")
       val prefix = "part-"

       listOfFiles.filter(_.startsWith(prefix)).map(println)
   }
}
```

We take the list and first apply a *filter* and then *map* each element.
You can add whatever logic you want inside the *map*.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function like this:

```
def listFiles(file: File, pattern: String): Array[File] = {
  val files = file.listFiles()
  val regex = pattern.r
  files
  .filter(f => f.isFile() && regex.findFirstIn(file.getName).isDefined)
  .toArray
}
```

And call it with `directory` and `pattern`. As you want all the files starting with `part-`, the pattern would be `part-*`. Below is the example call

```
val files = listFiles(new File("path), "part-*")
```